# How do I pass a parameter from HTML to server using href

Tags: html, forms, href

Hi I'm trying to invoque a servlet from a JSP page, what I want to do is to pass a parameter, well 2 parameters, but one of them is not static, it's the result of a select, this is my code:

```
<form>
    <select name="tipoReporte" id="tipoReporte">
        <option value="0" selected>Seleccione el tipo de reporte que desea ver:</option>
        <option value="sem">Semanal</option>
        <option value="2hrs">Cada dos horas</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

As you see, the user will choose an option and depending on it, my servlet will do different things, here's the code to pass my parameters to my servlet:

```
<a target=_blank href="servlet1?cmd=graphic_jetta&tipoReporte= ¿what should I pass? "> 
    <img src="images/je1.png" width="200" height="100" id="je" onmouseover="changeImage('images/je1.png', 'images/je2.PNG', 'je')" onmouseout="changeImage('images/je1.png', 'images/je1.png', 'je')"/>
</a>
```

Then on the servlet I use the `request.getParameter()` method, but my problem is that I don't know how to pass this value in the code above. For instance, the first parameter doesn't give me problem cause is static, but the second one is my problem.
I'm new in web developing, so I would appreciate your patience and help, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Create a JavaScript function for submitting:

```
function submit() {
    var tipoReporte = document.getElementById('tipoReporte').value;
    window.location.assign('servlet1?cmd=graphic_jetta&tipoReporte=' + tipoReporte);
}
```

and replace the link with:

```
<a target=_blank onclick="submit()">
```

or avoiding that, you can make the image part of the form:

```
<form action="servlet1">
    <select name="tipoReporte" id="tipoReporte">
        <option value="0" selected>Seleccione el tipo de reporte que desea ver:</option>
        <option value="sem">Semanal</option>
        <option value="2hrs">Cada dos horas</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="graphic_jetta">
    <input type="image" src="images/je1.png">
</form>
```